# how to include Imagick in PHP

Tags: php, imagick, php-include

I have a script to delete Exif data from image, I want to use Imagick library, I setup it with :

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
sudo apt-get install php5-imagick
```

then I wroth this code :

```
$img = new Imagick($getImage);
$img->stripImage();
$img->writeImage('new.jpg');
$img->destroy();
```

but I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'ImageUploader\Imagick' not found in /opt/uploader.php on line 210
```

any idea please ?

Comment: You are not loading the `php_imagick.dll` extension.

Comment: `$img = new \Imagick($getImage);`

Comment: It's good to specify what operating system you're on, in case that has something to do with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely you're in a class with the namespace `ImageUploader`, as we can see from your error message.

`Imagick` by default doesn't have a namespace, so we can instantiate the class with no namespace with a backslash (`\`)

```
$img = new \Imagick($getImage);
```

Comment: Perfect, that's what I missed :) Thx